# How can i change the confirm page text in simplenews

Tags: 7, emails

how can I change this text or translate it:

```
Are you sure you want to add s*****@y*****.com to the sizing mailing list?

You can always unsubscribe later.
```

this is the page after click on confirm link in email ?

I've tried string override module but it can't change that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grep on the simplenews module shows the text is coming from simplenews.subscription.inc file from following code.

on around line #582

```
/**
 * Generate the confirm subscription form.
 *
 * @see simplenews_confirm_add_form_submit()
 */
function simplenews_confirm_add_form($form, &$form_state, $mail, $newsletter) {
  $form = array();
  $form['question'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<p>' . t('Are you sure you want to add %user to the %newsletter mailing list?', array('%user' => simplenews_mask_mail($mail), '%newsletter' => _simplenews_newsletter_name($newsletter))) . "<p>\n",
  );
  $form['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $mail,
  );
  $form['newsletter'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $newsletter,
  );

  return confirm_form($form, t('Confirm subscription'), '', t('You can always unsubscribe later.'), t('Subscribe'), t('Cancel')
  );
}
```

since it is a form, you can simply implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to override 'question' field markup from your custom module, something of following sort

```
function my_module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'simplenews_confirm_add_form') {
      $form['question'] = array(
       '#markup' => t('Your Custom Confirmation Message Here'),
      );
  }
}
```